# Is it possible to make a class A in Javascript which "class extends A {} instanceof A" is true?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

Is it possible to make a class `A` (can be either an ES 6 class or an old-style constructor function) such that `class extends A {} instanceof A` is true?

If it is possible, please give me an example.
If it is not, please give me a proof.

Note that a class `B` such that `new B instanceof B` and `new new B instanceof B` are both true at the same time is possible by manipulating the prototype chain. It's possible to write a `B` such that `new B` satisfy the expected behaviour of a `class extends B {}`, but I would also like to investigate the possibility to make an `A` that `class extends A {}` satisfy the expected behaviour of `new A` as well.

This is related to [my code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213930/write-a-javascript-typescript-class-which-can-generate-subclasses-and-instance) which I have just posted, however in this question I would like to investigate the possibility of reverse - to make `class extends A {}` behaves like `new A`, while the code golf is to make `new A` behaves like `class extends A {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

First, the obvious values for `A` are `Object` and `Function`. These two will make the expression true.

For any other value of `A`, you would have to set its proto to its `prototype` property value:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(A, A.prototype);
```

I suppose this is just "for sports", as it would give unexpected results for other enquiries, like: `A instanceof Function`. By manipulating the prototype chain of `A`, this no longer is true. Still, `A` can be executed, because it still has the internal `[[Call]]` slot.

Here is a snippet illustrating the above:

```js
function test1() {
  let A = Object;
  console.log(class extends A {} instanceof A); // true
  A = Function;
  console.log(class extends A {} instanceof A); // true
}

function test2() {
  class A {
    speak() { console.log("hello") }
  }

  Object.setPrototypeOf(A, A.prototype);

  console.log(class extends A {} instanceof A); // true
  console.log(A instanceof Function); // false
  new A().speak(); // hello
}

test1();
test2();
```

Comment: I am thinking of making a class which can [pass this test](https://github.com/miklcct/js-self-reproducing-class/blob/main/test.ts#L7) with `new (getDerivedClass(level - 1))` replaced with `class extends getDerivedClass(level - 1) {}`. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not so familiar with test frameworks. If you have a new question, don't hesitate to post it, providing the necessary tags, which will determine who will be attracted to your question.